# PHP Getting SUM of Array Values While Comparing

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of Information States And Totals. I want to see how to get the Total of all the Totals for each state.

I know I have to use a loop but I am not sure which - what would I do?

This is what I have so far. It's making the array from a database.

```
$WorkFind = mysql_query(
  "SELECT Customers.State, WorkOrders.Total 
   FROM WorkOrders 
   INNER JOIN Customers 
   ON WorkOrders.CID=Customers.ID 
   WHERE WorkOrders.Type <> 'Warranty' 
   AND (WorkOrders.Status <> 'Closed' 
   OR WorkOrders.Status <> 'Cancelled') 
   AND WorkOrders.TransferID='0' 
   ORDER BY Customers.State ASC");

while ($Work = mysql_fetch_array($WorkFind)) { 
}
```

The while loop has made the array  but I'm unsure what to put into it.

I'm using PHP 5.3 and MYSQL 5.2

Comment: code example asap please

Comment: How does your array look like? What is the problem with [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/foreach)?

Comment: Give us a part of the array and the solution you want.

Comment: Added code to the original post.

Comment: You can format code blocks by indenting them with 4 spaces (or select the code and click on the curly braces above the text field)

Comment: Have you thought about using SQL [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html)?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @kero sorry for the late reply this was old code and the code below by Pascal got it working. I don't usually code in MySQL like that but I would have to figure out the syntax to do the SUM() using PHP and PDO.

Comment: @JukEboX Late is an understatement .. Jk, glad to hear you got it working - no matter how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$WorkFind = mysql_query("SELECT Customers.State AS State, WorkOrders.Total AS Total -- ...");

$total = array();

while ($Work = mysql_fetch_array($WorkFind)) {
  $state = $Work['State'];

  if (!isset($total[$state])) {
    $total[$state] = 0;
  }

  $total[$state] += $Work['Total'];
}

// format as simple table

echo '<table><tr><th>State</th><th>Total</th></tr>';

foreach ($total as $state_name => $state_total) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $state_name . '</td><td>' . $state_total . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: That only gives me the total of all the work total. I need the total for each state.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. You can use an array, I added it to the code above.

Comment: One more question. How do I format this if it comes out like this.

Array ( [CT] => 35774.56 [DE] => 1779 [FL] => 9519.87 [MA] => 11875.82 [MD] => 87722.98 [NJ] => 212389.21 [NY] => 194354.32 [PA] => 31449.43 [RI] => 2872.56 [VA] => 61398.72 )

Comment: You can use a foreach loop. I added one in the answer to output a table with the calculated values. With ```foreach ($total as $state_name => $state_total)``` you iterate over the ```$total``` array and set a variable ```$state_name``` to the current element's key (CT, DE, FL, ...) and a second variable ```$state_total``` to the element's value.